# getView() in ArrayAdapter is saying Row 1 is position 0 instead of correct position 1

Tags: java, android, android-studio, listview, android-arrayadapter

**The Problem**

I have a `ListView` with a `TextView` and `EditText`. I have a `addTextChangeListener()` on the EditText so I can save the text immediately into the `ArrayList` so I can retrieve it in the parent activity. *For some reason, when I am on row 1, it thinks the position is row 0 and it saves the `EditText` information from Row 1 into position 0 of the Array. And it continues on to save Row 1 information into position 1 of the Array. So I have a double of Row 1 information. Everything else after that is completely normal.

Does anybody have any idea of how to solve this?

---

**ArrayAdapter**

```
class CustomListViewEntryAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ThoughtClass> {

private ArrayList<ThoughtClass> mListOfThoughtClass;
private ThoughtClass mThoughtClass;
private int mNumberOfThought;
private String mThoughtEntry;

static class ViewHolder {
    CardView cardView;
    EditText editText;
    TextView textView;
}

public CustomListViewEntryAdapter(@NonNull Context context, ArrayList<ThoughtClass> thoughtClass) {
    super(context, R.layout.listview_entry_edittext_row ,thoughtClass);

    mListOfThoughtClass = thoughtClass;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(final int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder viewHolder;
    View currentView = convertView;

    if(convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater davidsInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        currentView = davidsInflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_entry_edittext_row, parent, false);

        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.cardView = currentView.findViewById(R.id.thoughtCard);
        viewHolder.textView = currentView.findViewById(R.id.thoughtNumber);
        viewHolder.editText = currentView.findViewById(R.id.thoughtEntry);

        // associate the holder with the view for later lookup
        currentView.setTag(viewHolder);
    }
    else {
        // view already exists, get the holder instance from the view
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) currentView.getTag();
    }

    viewHolder.editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            mListOfThoughtClass.get(position).setThoughtEntry(s.toString());
        }
    });

    mThoughtClass = mListOfThoughtClass.get(position);
    mNumberOfThought = mThoughtClass.getNumberOfThought();
    if(mThoughtClass.getThoughtEntry() == null) {
        mThoughtEntry = "";
    }
    else {
        mThoughtEntry = mThoughtClass.getThoughtEntry();
    }

    // Set objects
    viewHolder.textView.setText( Integer.toString(mNumberOfThought) );
    if(!mThoughtEntry.equals("") || mThoughtEntry != null) {
        viewHolder.editText.setText(mThoughtEntry);
    }

    return currentView;
}
}
```

**ThoughtClass**

```
public class ThoughtClass {

private int mNumberOfThought;
private String mThoughtEntry;
private StorageDistortions mStorageDistortions;

public ThoughtClass(int numberOfThought) {
    this.mNumberOfThought = numberOfThought;
    this.mThoughtEntry = "";
    this.mStorageDistortions = new StorageDistortions();
}

public ThoughtClass(int numberOfThought, String thoughtEntry){
    this.mNumberOfThought = numberOfThought;
    this.mThoughtEntry = thoughtEntry;
}

public ThoughtClass(int numberOfThought, StorageDistortions storageDistortions){
    this.mNumberOfThought = numberOfThought;
    this.mStorageDistortions = storageDistortions;
}

public int getNumberOfThought() {
    return mNumberOfThought;
}

public void setNumberOfThought(int numberOfThought) {
    mNumberOfThought = numberOfThought;
}

public String getThoughtEntry() {
    return mThoughtEntry;
}

public void setThoughtEntry(String thoughtEntry) {
    mThoughtEntry = thoughtEntry;
}

public StorageDistortions getStorageDistortions() {
    return mStorageDistortions;
}

public void setStorageDistortions(StorageDistortions storageDistortions) {
    mStorageDistortions = storageDistortions;
}
}
```

**Edit**
I forgot to mention this part. In the parent view there is an add button that introduces a new member to the adapter. I do not believe this would affect the positioning though.

```
public void addNewThought() {
    ThoughtClass thoughtClass = new ThoughtClass(++mNumberOfThoughts);
    mThoughtClassList.add( thoughtClass );

    setListViewHeightBasedOnItems(mNegativeThoughtsListView);
    mNegativeThoughtsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public boolean setListViewHeightBasedOnItems(ListView listView) {

    ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter();
    mThoughtClassList = mNegativeThoughtsAdapter.getItems();
    if (listAdapter != null) {

        int numberOfItems = listAdapter.getCount();

        // Get total height of all mItems.
        int totalItemsHeight = 0;
        for (int itemPos = 0; itemPos < numberOfItems; itemPos++) {
            View item = listAdapter.getView(itemPos, null, listView);
            item.measure(0, 0);
            totalItemsHeight += item.getMeasuredHeight();
        }

        // Get total height of all item dividers.
        int totalDividersHeight = listView.getDividerHeight() *
                (numberOfItems - 1);

        // Set list height.
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
        params.height = totalItemsHeight + totalDividersHeight;
        listView.setLayoutParams(params);
        listView.requestLayout();

        return true;

    } else {
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: Just to be clear. Most humans count rows in a list starting with "one" for the very first entry. Java `ArrayList` objects count indices starting with "zero"! So when you say "...Row 1 is position 0..."  are you counting the rows starting at zero or one?

Comment: @Barns sorry for the confusion. I'm counting rows starting at 0. I wanted to show that row 0 things are in position 0 and row 1 things are in position 1

Comment: Ok. good to know. I assume you are having issues in this line of code: `mListOfThoughtClass.get(position).setThoughtEntry(s.toString());` I have never seen `getView()` get the position of an entry wrong...so that leads me to believe that the issue could be in `ThoughtClass`. Could you edit your question and add the `ThoughtClass` code?

Comment: @Barns Thanks! That's what I believe as well. I have it in debug mode  but the listener gets called a lot when I type a letter making it difficult to follow

Comment: Sorry for the delay... I am also working on my own code, now. One thing you could try would be to check if there is a difference between the `position` and the index of the `ArrayList`. In your `afterTextChanged()` method add this:  `int myIndex = mListOfThoughtClass.indexOf(mListOfThoughtClass.get(position));` This might show different values for `myIndex` and `position`. If they are the same then the issue is probably in the `ThoughtClass`. It seems there could be some issue with the `setNumberOfThought()` method. Be sure the first entry is zero.

Comment: you are calling `addTextChangedListener` each time `getView` is called? do you know how many `TextWatcher`s you will create?